# How to filter processes with "ps" to match all conditions?

Tags: linux, command-line, ps

In Linux, if I use `ps --user john -C processname`, then I get all processes owned by the user and *in addition* all processes named `processname`.

Is there a way to modify the behavior to get only processes called `processname` owned by `john`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `ps` is a bit strange in that way. You can use `pgrep` to help `ps`. In `pgrep` all conditions must match. Use that syntax for example:

```
ps -p"$(pgrep -d, -u john processname)"
```

`pgrep` prints all the pids comma separated that match the conditions. That is given to `ps` as an argument to the `-p` flag. `-p` selects a list of pids.